# OpenGL 3.3 no texture gets rendered (black texture, C++, GLFW/SOIL)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glfw

I'm currently learning OpenGL 3.3 using C++ and GLFW (and SOIL for loading image files to create textures). I've implemented a batch rendering system that takes vertex information, maps the VBO data to a buffer variable, writes submitted vertex information to that buffer every frame and renders said frame.

The renderer.cpp looks like this: http://pastebin.com/N6nWdew6 while the VertexData struct is defined in the renderer.hpp as:

```
struct VertexData {
    VertexData()
        :   vertex(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)),
            color(glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)),
            texCoord(glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)),
            tid(0) {};

    VertexData(glm::vec3 vertex, glm::vec4 color, glm::vec2 texCoord, GLuint tid)
        :   vertex(vertex),
            color(color),
            texCoord(texCoord),
            tid(tid) {};

    ~VertexData() {};

    glm::vec3   vertex;
    glm::vec4   color;
    glm::vec2   texCoord;
    GLuint      tid;
};
```

Now, submitting and rendering actual vertices, color information, texture coordinates etc. seems to work, but the texture still doesn't get rendered, all I get is a black square. The most important bits of the actual submission in the main loop look like this (warning: looks bad, just for testing purposes; I tried to shorten it the best I could):

```
[...]

/*Static variables in the window class, just for testing purposes*/
Shader*                 Window::_exampleShader = nullptr;
Texture*                Window::_exampleTexture = nullptr;
Renderer::VertexData    Window::vA;
Renderer::VertexData    Window::vB;
Renderer::VertexData    Window::vC;
Renderer::VertexData    Window::vD;

[...]

/*Initialization in the window constructor*/
_exampleShader  = new Shader("../src/glsl/basicVertex.glsl", "../src/glsl/basicFragment.glsl");
_exampleTexture = new Texture("../res/test.png");

/*TOP LEFT*/
vA.vertex       = glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
vA.color        = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vA.texCoord     = glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f);
vA.tid          = _exampleTexture->getTextureID();

/*TOP RIGHT*/
vB.vertex       = glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
vB.color        = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vB.texCoord     = glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f);
vB.tid          = _exampleTexture->getTextureID();

/*BOTTOM LEFT*/
vC.vertex       = glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
vC.color        = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vC.texCoord     = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
vC.tid          = _exampleTexture->getTextureID();

/*BOTTOM RIGHT*/
vD.vertex       = glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
vD.color        = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vD.texCoord     = glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f);
vD.tid          = _exampleTexture->getTextureID();

[...]

/*Submission in the main loop*/
_exampleShader->bind();
_exampleTexture->bind();

_exampleShader->setUniformMat4("model_matrix", glm::mat4(1.0f));
_exampleShader->setUniformMat4("view_matrix", glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)));
_exampleShader->setUniformMat4("projection_matrix", glm::perspective(ConversionUtils::convertFOV(90.0f), getAspectRatio(), 0.0001f, 100.0f));

Renderer::begin();      
    Renderer::submit(vC);
    Renderer::submit(vA);
    Renderer::submit(vB);

    Renderer::submit(vC);
    Renderer::submit(vD);
    Renderer::submit(vB);
Renderer::end();

glfwSwapBuffers(_window);

[...]
```

As you can see, I create some example vertex data and submit that every frame. Now, the last bits of code are my vertex and fragment shaders:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 v_vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 v_color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 v_texCoord;
layout(location = 3) in uint v_tid;

out vec4 f_color;
out vec2 f_texCoord;
flat out uint f_tid;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main() {
    f_color     = v_color;
    f_texCoord  = v_texCoord;
    f_tid       = v_tid;

    mat4 mvp = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(v_vertex, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 f_color;
in vec2 f_texCoord;
flat in uint f_tid;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void main() {
    color = texture(texSampler, f_texCoord);
}
```

That's what I'm working with. Now, I already did a bunch of googling and even asked on the OpenGL channel @ freenode, but no one could help me with this. I removed deprecated functionality by using the core 3.3 profile, even the forward compatible profile, despite the fact that I should not be doing this. Other things I already checked:

- I'm only using one thread with a valid GL context, so there's probably no problems regarding "packaging an OGL object in a C++ class"
- Both the shader and the texture are bound; since the texture sampler and the active texture are 0 by default, that shouldn't cause any problems either
- I am actually loading test.png properly (texture.cpp if you're interested: http://pastebin.com/hWGTCe5C)
- I am not using deprecated functionality afaik, even the SOIL functions that use deprecated functionality aren't called; loading the image via SDL2 und SDL2_image, which I did before switching libraries, caused the same problem
- The shader gets valid texture coordinates (tested by outputting them as colors to the square I'm rendering)
- Neither the shader nor the compiler give me any warnings/errors, despite the -Wall compiler flag being set, glGetError() doesn't help either

Other information that might be useful: I've tested this on both Intel and Nvidia GPUs using their most recent drivers on Antergos (Arch) Linux (one on Wayland, one on X11). 64-bit architecture. Most recent versions of the libraries (GLFW3, SOIL, GLEW and GLM). Compiled using Clang++. Valgrind doesn't give me any useful output either.

Me and the IRC chatroom are running out of ideas - what could cause this?

Comment: What texture sampling parameters are you using? A classic mistake is to leave `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` at its default value, which is for mipmapped sampling, but not have mipmaps for the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RetoKoradi said in his comment, you are not actually passing any parameters to your texture, therefore your texture is not complete.

Try to add in texture.cpp something like :

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, your_internal_format, width, height, 0, your_format, your_type, texture_pointer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, your_behavior);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, your_behavior);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

or

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

or

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
```

you can find more informations about texture completness here : [OpenGL Common Mistakes](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture). Note that the problem @RetoKoradi is refering about is addressed in this link.

Comment: You two just fixed my problem! Thank you so much, this was driving me insane!